Reasoning for reduced SVD factorization
I am aware that for any $m \times n$ matrix $A$, we can write:
Known 1: $A = U\Sigma V^T$ where $U$ is orthogonal and $m \times m$, $V$ is orthogonal and $n\times n$, and $\Sigma$ is diagonal and $m \times n$, OR
Known 2: $A = U_r D V_r^T$ where $U_r$ is $m \times r$ and has orthonormal columns, $V_r$ is $n \times r$ and has orthonormal columns, $D$ is the $r \times r$ diagonal matrix of positive singular values of $A$, and $r$ is the rank of $A$.
However, I cannot resolve the following "contradiction". I know I must be missing something - any help would be appreciated!
Let $v_1$, ..., $v_r$ be orthonormal eigenvectors of $A^T A$ with positive eigenvalues. Let $V$ be a matrix with $v_1, ..., v_r$ as its columns. Then letting $u_i = Av_i/|Av_i|$ for $1 \leq i \leq r$ and $U$ be a matrix with $u_1, ..., u_r$ as its columns, then it is clear that $AV_r = U_rD$. It is at this point I get lost. If you multiply both sides by $V_r^T$, we get $AV_rV_r^T = U_rDV_r^T$. However, $AV_rV_r^T \neq A$ since $V_rV_r^T \neq I$. This seems to contradict Known 2. What am I missing?

Hint: $V_rV_r^T$ is an orthogonal projector onto the orthogonal compliment of the null space of $A$.

Oh, that's right.. so $V_r V_r^T A^T = A^T$ , and transposing each side gives the desired result. Thank you!!!
